# Use a volatile paramet inside a virtual function

Tags: c++, function, virtual, volatile

virtual void doEventLoop(char volatile* watchVariable);

I tried to implement above method and it gave me an error (Says it is abstract)

So without using volatile I can be able compile it successfully.
Where the issue will be?

Comment: You cannot use `volatile` on an argument that you pass to a function!!! It doesn't make sense anyway, because `volatile` is in order to indicate to the compiler that this variable can change from somewhere outside the function.

Comment: Actually I have faced this issue when compiling live555 liveMedia.

Comment: "Says it is abstract". Says *what* is abstract? When does it say it? For what code?

Answer (score 0):

Your description if the problem is lacking, to say the least.

But from what you provided so far I'd guess that this method is supposed to override a pure virtual method in some base class. In the base class the method's signature does not have that `volatile` there. Which means that you cannot just suddenly add that `volatile`. If you add `volatile`, you declare a completely different virtual method, which does not override the one from base class. The base method remains non-overridden (i.e. pure), and the class remains abstract.

Comment: Its there in the header as well.

Comment: @Shamendra: If `volatile` is there in the base class as well, then what you are describing sounds like some unexplainable magic. There must be something else involved, of which you are not telling us.

Comment: Actually this is in live555 codebase. I removed that volatile from pure virtual function and other implementations. So then after that it can be compile.